# Select Min And Max Value from one table with same id in one row (sql server)

Tags: sql-server, max, min

I have table like this:

```
| ID |        Date         |
|----|---------------------|
| 20 | 2017-03-01 08:00:00 |
| 20 | 2017-03-01 17:00:00 |
| 21 | 2017-03-01 07:00:00 |
| 21 | 2017-03-01 17:10:00 |
```

How can I select that to show result like this:

```
| ID |        Date         |        IN          |        OUT         |
|----|---------------------|--------------------|--------------------|
| 20 |      2017-03-01     |2017-03-01 08:00:00 |2017-03-01 17:00:00 |
| 21 |      2017-03-01     |2017-03-01 07:00:00 |2017-03-01 17:10:00 |
```

I can't find out the query, please help me, thank you in advance

Comment: thanks for your reply..this is what i did:SELECT ID, Datel,  (SELECT MIN(Date) FROM Absensi_Log WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-03-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-09 23:59:59') AS IN,  (SELECT MAX(Date) FROM Absensi_Log WHERE Date BETWEEN 
        '2017-03-03 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-09 23:59:59') AS OUT FROM Absensi_Log WHERE Date BETWEEN '2017-03-03 00:00:00' AND '2017-03-09 23:59:59' GROUP BY ID, Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query will return, minimum date as IN time and maximum date as OUT time for each ID.

```
SELECT  ID,CONVERT(DATE,([DATE]) ) AS [DATE],MIN([DATE]) AS [IN],MAX([DATE]) AS [OUT]
FROM    TABLE1
GROUP BY ID,CONVERT(DATE,([DATE]) )
```

Note:- Please don't use the SQL KEYWORD as column name ( eg;- DATE,IN,OUT...)

Comment: It works like a charm! thank you for your help sir!

Comment: @YohanWijayanto, don't use the SQL KEYWORD as column name ( eg;- DATE,IN,OUT...) that will cause problems in your query.

Comment: Thank you for your advice!, i'll change the keywords.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following query.

```
SELECT id, MIN(date), MAX(date) FROM yourTable GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**: Aggregate function `MIN,MAX` and `GROUP BY` will solve your problem and provide you the expected result as below:

```
select id, cast(Edate as Date) EDate, min(Edate) inTime, max(Edate) outTime 
from myTable
group by id, cast(Edate as Date)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
id  EDate       inTime                  outTime
20  2017-03-01  2017-03-01 08:00:00.000 2017-03-01 17:00:00.000
21  2017-03-01  2017-03-01 07:00:00.000 2017-03-01 17:10:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer!, i can't figure it out without your help. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  to_char(DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  MIN(DATE) AS IN,
  MAX(DATE) AS OUT
FROM Absensi_Log outer
GROUP BY ID,to_char(DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

With sub-query

```
SELECT
  ID,
  (SELECT
    to_char(DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  FROM Absensi_Log sub
  WHERE sub.id = outer.id
  GROUP BY to_char(DATE, 'yyyy-mm-dd')),
  MIN(DATE) AS IN,
  MAX(DATE) AS OUT
FROM Absensi_Log outer
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP (Id INT,[Date] DATETIME)
INSERT INTO #Temp 
SELECT 20,'2017-03-01 08:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 20,'2017-03-01 17:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 21,'2017-03-01 07:00:00' UNION ALL
SELECT 21,'2017-03-01 17:10:00'

SELECT Id,CONVERT(DATE,[Date],103)[Date],Min([Date]) DateIN,Max([Date]) DateOUT FROM #Temp
GROUP BY Id,CONVERT(DATE,[Date],103)

DROP TABLE #Temp
```